# Does this formula for the amplitude of a Chebyshev filter at cornerfrequentie only hold for even orders?

Tags: active-filter

Consider formula (4) below that gives the amplitude of the transfer function of a Chebyshev filter at cornerfrequentie. When I try to re-derive it, it seems to me that this only holds true for even \$n\$'s.

[image: Chebyshev filter amplitude transfer function at cornerfrequency]

Granted, I don't understand the meaning of taking an arccos of a complex number, but I think that question is better suited for another forum. Wolfram Alpha gives me \$\cos^{-1}(j) = \frac{j\pi}{2}\$.

I assume \$0 < n < 3, n \in \mathbb{N} \$ is the only relevant scope in this context, but this contains \$n = 1 \$ in which case, it seems to me, (4) does not apply.

Is my math wrong or can \$n\$ never be odd for a ChebyShev filter, if so why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Chebyshev responses, the given formulas do apply for n=2 as well as n>2 (even and odd).
Please note that in case n=1 we have a simple first order lowpass response - and it is NOT possible to discriminate between Butterworth, Chebyshev, Bessel,....

Background: For Chebyshev filters, the corner frequency is defined at the end of the "ripple band" - however, a first-order response does not exhibit any ripple at all.